# separate multiple jpg files from a single file

Tags: java, file, io

I have merged multiple jpeg files into one single .bin file.

```
.....
.........
while(true){
             if (q.numOfFiles() > 0) {
              source = q.getNextFile();
              in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source)));
               byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
               int len;
               while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
               }
               String s = "filename=="+source.getName()+"==filename";
               out.write(s.getBytes());
               out.flush();
               System.out.println("merged--"+source.getName());
             }
                }
........
........
```

as you can see i am appending "filename=="+source.getName()+"==filename" after end of each file.
Now i want to separate all those jpegs with their actual file names.
How can i read the separators that I've inserted in the merged files ?

Comment: i would suggest using a single file, perhaps zip?
[How to create zip in Java](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.zip/CreateZip.html)

Comment: @pedroFerreira that would be very simple. but i don't want anyone to extract the images just by using winzip..

Comment: you can extract them in Java also.
[Extract from zip in Java](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/corejava/zip/extract.html)

Comment: I am not completely certain about this, because I am no expert. But to me, your method seems flawed. It does not seem impossible that the binary data of the image files just perchance happen to contain a sequence of bits which, if translated to ASCII, would read "filename==something.jpg==filename". When decoding, it would be completely impossible to distinguish between a real separator, and a sequence of bits which just perchance has the same format as your separator. You need a more solid protocol for deciding when new files start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As above in the comments:
Sugestion/answer to adapt your point of view:

Using a single file zip to ship multiple files.

[How to create zip in Java](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.zip/CreateZip.html)

And to extract:

[Extract from zip in Java](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/corejava/zip/extract.html)